# any two points on contact manifold connected by a path tangent to the contact distribution

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M, B)$ be a manifold with a subbundle $B \subset TM$ such that the Frobenius tensor $B \times B \to TM/B$ given by the commutator of vector fields is non-degenerate. Is it true that any two points $x, y \in M$ can be connected by a piecewise smooth path tangent to $B$?

Comment: Did you mean to ask about a contact manifold, or about a manifold with a subbundle $B \subset TM$ such that $[B, B] \cap B \neq \emptyset$? They are two very different things.

Comment: Dear Jack, sorry, I indeed incorrectly judged this to be an equivalent statement. I meant a contact manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer yes, by the [Chow–Rashevskii theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%E2%80%93Rashevskii_theorem). (That theorem applies more generally, to sub-Riemannian metrics whose horizontal distributions are bracket-generating, meaning that every tangent vector at every point can be expressed as a Lie bracket of finitely many vector fields tangent to the horizontal distribution. Contact manifolds always satisfy this condition.)

Comment: Thank you! I have spent some time trying to prove it myself, and I tried moving along the flows integrating the vector fields tangent to $B$ but I was clueless as to how to move in the directions "orthogonal" to $B$. Now I have realized after looking up the proof in the book of Montgomery that I have overlooked that I can also move in the directions of commutators of vector fields tangent $B$, and so can sweep a small neighbourhood of a point with geodesics tangent to $B$.